# Mauze over functionality is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

public class AdminUser {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.carmax.com/");

    Actions builder= new Actions(driver);
    WebElement d= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/header/div/nav[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
    builder.moveToElement(d).build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Why CarMax?")).click();

}



}
I am getting o/p as:
```

1490543196098   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:7086
1490543196344   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path /var/folders/dg/glyvppvs1dn31sqrrgt7yhjc0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.l2gu30iSNpnT
1490543196345   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin with args []
1490543196348   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:59046
1490543197117   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 59046
Mar 26, 2017 9:16:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2017-03-26 21:16:39.067 plugin-container[2943:127691] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9337, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-03-26 21:16:39.072 plugin-container[2943:127691] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x933b, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
JavaScript warning: https://s-cdn-tag.medialytics.com/cp, line 19: Error: WebGL: getParameter: parameter: invalid enum value 
JavaScript warning: https://s-cdn-tag.medialytics.com/cp, line 19: Error: WebGL: getParameter: parameter: invalid enum value 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'Javeds-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fd50:1d9:9d9b:eb00:14:5aa0:4eca:be9d', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/var/folders/dg/glyvppvs1dn31sqrrgt7yhjc0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.l2gu30iSNpnT, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0.1, platformVersion=16.4.0, moz:processID=2941, browserName=firefox, platformName=darwin}]
Session ID: ae3c536b-197f-8941-91b4-f630e7a4dab5
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at AdminUser.main(AdminUser.java:24)

Comment: Can you provide some more information as:  1. What are you trying to do? 2. Check other thread discussion threads on how to set System Properties. 3. Why are you jumping to use Action class?

Comment: Please remember to work on the solutions provided by our experts investing their valuable time on the questions you ask and either update with the current status or Close the discussion if a solution to your Question have been identified. Thanks.